# Hyperlink doesn't redirect user with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click the blue text `Learn more` I want to redirect to Google, however, it just closes the div.

The link is on **Line 146** of my Javascript.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4190n96u/)

```js
/**
 *  
 * JQUERY EU COOKIE LAW POPUPS
 * version 1.0.0
 * 
 * Code on Github:
 * https://github.com/wimagguc/jquery-eu-cookie-law-popup
 * 
 * To see a live demo, go to:
 * http://www.wimagguc.com/2015/04/jquery-eu-cookie-law-popup/
 * 
 * by Richard Dancsi
 * http://www.wimagguc.com/
 * 
 */

(function($) {

// for ie9 doesn't support debug console >>>
if (!window.console) window.console = {};
if (!window.console.log) window.console.log = function () { };
// ^^^

var EuCookieLawPopup = (function() {

 var _self = this;

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // PARAMETERS (MODIFY THIS PART) //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 _self.params = {
  cookiePolicyUrl : '/cookie-privacy-policy/',
  popupPosition : 'bottom',
  colorStyle : 'default',
  compactStyle : false,
  popupTitle : 'This site uses cookies to store information on your computer',
  popupText : '',
  buttonContinueTitle : 'Learn more',
  buttonLearnmoreTitle : 'Learn&nbsp;more',
  buttonLearnmoreOpenInNewWindow : true,
  agreementExpiresInDays : 30,
  autoAcceptCookiePolicy : true,
  htmlMarkup : null
 };

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // VARIABLES USED BY THE FUNCTION (DON'T MODIFY THIS PART) ////////////////////////////////////
 _self.vars = {
  INITIALISED : false,
  HTML_MARKUP : null,
  COOKIE_NAME : 'EU_COOKIE_LAW_CONSENT'
 };

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // PRIVATE FUNCTIONS FOR MANIPULATING DATA ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 // Overwrite default parameters if any of those is present
 var parseParameters = function(object, markup, settings) {

  if (object) {
   var className = $(object).attr('class') ? $(object).attr('class') : '';
   if (className.indexOf('eupopup-top') > -1) {
    _self.params.popupPosition = 'top';
   }
   else if (className.indexOf('eupopup-fixedtop') > -1) {
    _self.params.popupPosition = 'fixedtop';
   }
   else if (className.indexOf('eupopup-bottomright') > -1) {
    _self.params.popupPosition = 'bottomright';
   }
   else if (className.indexOf('eupopup-bottomleft') > -1) {
    _self.params.popupPosition = 'bottomleft';
   }
   else if (className.indexOf('eupopup-bottom') > -1) {
    _self.params.popupPosition = 'bottom';
   }
   else if (className.indexOf('eupopup-block') > -1) {
    _self.params.popupPosition = 'block';
   }
   if (className.indexOf('eupopup-color-default') > -1) {
    _self.params.colorStyle = 'default';
   }
   else if (className.indexOf('eupopup-color-inverse') > -1) {
    _self.params.colorStyle = 'inverse';
   }
   if (className.indexOf('eupopup-style-compact') > -1) {
    _self.params.compactStyle = true;
   }
  }

  if (markup) {
   _self.params.htmlMarkup = markup;
  }

  if (settings) {
   if (typeof settings.cookiePolicyUrl !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.cookiePolicyUrl = settings.cookiePolicyUrl;
   }
   if (typeof settings.popupPosition !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.popupPosition = settings.popupPosition;
   }
   if (typeof settings.colorStyle !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.colorStyle = settings.colorStyle;
   }
   if (typeof settings.popupTitle !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.popupTitle = settings.popupTitle;
   }
   if (typeof settings.popupText !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.popupText = settings.popupText;
   }
   if (typeof settings.buttonContinueTitle !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.buttonContinueTitle = settings.buttonContinueTitle;
   }
   if (typeof settings.buttonLearnmoreTitle !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.buttonLearnmoreTitle = settings.buttonLearnmoreTitle;
   }
   if (typeof settings.buttonLearnmoreOpenInNewWindow !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.buttonLearnmoreOpenInNewWindow = settings.buttonLearnmoreOpenInNewWindow;
   }
   if (typeof settings.agreementExpiresInDays !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.agreementExpiresInDays = settings.agreementExpiresInDays;
   }
   if (typeof settings.autoAcceptCookiePolicy !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.autoAcceptCookiePolicy = settings.autoAcceptCookiePolicy;
   }
   if (typeof settings.htmlMarkup !== 'undefined') {
    _self.params.htmlMarkup = settings.htmlMarkup;
   }
  }

 };

 var createHtmlMarkup = function() {

  if (_self.params.htmlMarkup) {
   return _self.params.htmlMarkup;
  }

  var html = 
   '<div class="eupopup-container' + 
       ' eupopup-container-' + _self.params.popupPosition + 
       (_self.params.compactStyle ? ' eupopup-style-compact' : '') + 
    ' eupopup-color-' + _self.params.colorStyle + '">' +
    '<div class="eupopup-head">' + _self.params.popupTitle + '</div>' +
    '<div class="eupopup-body">' + _self.params.popupText + '</div>' +
    '<div class="eupopup-buttons">' +
      '<a href="http://www.google.com/" class="eupopup-button eupopup-button_1">' + _self.params.buttonContinueTitle + '</a>' +
      '<a href="' + _self.params.cookiePolicyUrl + '"' +
      (_self.params.buttonLearnmoreOpenInNewWindow ? ' target=_blank ' : '') +
     ' class="eupopup-button eupopup-button_2">' + _self.params.buttonLearnmoreTitle + '</a>' +
      '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<a href="#" class="eupopup-closebutton"><img src="/images/icons/svg/close.svg"></a>' +
   '</div>';

  return html;
 };

 // Storing the consent in a cookie
 var setUserAcceptsCookies = function(consent) {
  var d = new Date();
  var expiresInDays = _self.params.agreementExpiresInDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  d.setTime( d.getTime() + expiresInDays );
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = _self.vars.COOKIE_NAME + '=' + consent + "; " + expires + ";path=/";

  $(document).trigger("user_cookie_consent_changed", {'consent' : consent});
 };

 // Let's see if we have a consent cookie already
 var userAlreadyAcceptedCookies = function() {
  var userAcceptedCookies = false;
  var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
  for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
   var c = cookies[i].trim();
   if (c.indexOf(_self.vars.COOKIE_NAME) == 0) {
    userAcceptedCookies = c.substring(_self.vars.COOKIE_NAME.length + 1, c.length);
   }
  }

  return userAcceptedCookies;
 };
 
 var hideContainer = function() {
  // $('.eupopup-container').slideUp(200);
  $('.eupopup-container').animate({
   opacity: 0,
   height: 0
  }, 200, function() {
   $('.eupopup-container').hide(0);
  });
 };

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // PUBLIC FUNCTIONS  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 var publicfunc = {

  // INITIALIZE EU COOKIE LAW POPUP /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  init : function(settings) {

   parseParameters(
    $(".eupopup").first(),
    $(".eupopup-markup").html(),
    settings);

   // No need to display this if user already accepted the policy
   if (userAlreadyAcceptedCookies()) {
    return;
   }

   // We should initialise only once
   if (_self.vars.INITIALISED) {
    return;
   }
   _self.vars.INITIALISED = true;

   // Markup and event listeners >>>
   _self.vars.HTML_MARKUP = createHtmlMarkup();

   if ($('.eupopup-block').length > 0) {
    $('.eupopup-block').append(_self.vars.HTML_MARKUP);
   } else {
    $('BODY').append(_self.vars.HTML_MARKUP);
   }

   $('.eupopup-button_1').click(function() {
    setUserAcceptsCookies(true);
    hideContainer();
    return false;
   });
   $('.eupopup-closebutton').click(function() {
    setUserAcceptsCookies(true);
    hideContainer();
    return false;
   });
   // ^^^ Markup and event listeners

   // Ready to start!
   $('.eupopup-container').show();

   // In case it's alright to just display the message once 
   if (_self.params.autoAcceptCookiePolicy) {
    setUserAcceptsCookies(true);
   }

  }

 };

 return publicfunc;
});

$(document).ready( function() {
 if ($(".eupopup").length > 0) {
  (new EuCookieLawPopup()).init({
   'info' : 'YOU_CAN_ADD_MORE_SETTINGS_HERE',
   'popupTitle' : 'This site uses cookies to store information on your computer',
   'popupText' : '',
   'buttonLearnmoreTitle' : ''
  });
 }
});

}(jQuery));
```

```css
.eupopup-container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 190;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
    background: #4a4a4a;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    display: block;
}

.nav {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  margin-top: 64px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="nav">
    
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x300">
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: you have edit jsfiddle, because now there is not any learn more links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('.eupopup-button_1').click(function() {
    setUserAcceptsCookies(true);
    hideContainer();
    return false;
});
```

This ***return false;*** should be the reason, please remove it.

Comment: Thanks @michaelmcgurk for accepting my answer , I am glad it made your work

Answer (score 2):

you need to do two things

1) Comment out line number 228

```
$('.eupopup-button_1').click(function() {
    setUserAcceptsCookies(true);
    hideContainer();
    //return false;
});
```

2) Ensure that the link that you are pointing to doesn't have X-Frame options set otherwise it will give the error like it is giving now

> Refused to display
>   'https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=Gb9nVtCHHu_I8AeltLGYBQ&gws_rd=ssl'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.